# I want to Add custom property from php object class

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add new property for each object. My code is shown below:

```
 function getCitationDataofquotes($var1){
    $query = "SELECT `id`,`title`,`source`,`content`,`page`,`city`,`publisher` FROM `#__gpo_citations_quotes`";
    $query .= " WHERE `id`='" . $var1 . "'";
    if (!empty($query))
    {
        $some= array();
        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $data = $this->_db->loadObject();
        return $data; 

    }
 $value = $datapages->getCitationDataofquotes($var1);
 $getdataofcitation['citations'][] = $value;
```

Then my output of this return data is below

```
{id: "12091",
title: "Homicide Victims by Year and Jurisdiction, 1989–90 to 2010–12",
source: "Homicide in Australia: 2010–11 to 2011–12: National Homicide Monitoring Program report",
content: " ACT = Australian Capital Territory]",
page: "p. 37",
city: "Canberra",
publisher: "Australian Institute of Criminology"
},

{
id: "8901",
title: "test",
source: null,
content: "",
page: null,
city: null,
publisher: null
},
```

Now I want to add new property for each object. I want this output for each object.

```
{ id: "8901",
 title: "test",
 source: null,
 content: "",
 page: null,
 city: null,
 publisher: null ,
 **new property: something**}
```

Comment: Please format your post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your $query is vulnerable to Sql-injection. BTW there are multiple ways to achieve the results you want. e.g you can add properties in the query instead:

```
SELECT 'some value' As `some_field` ...
```

If you want to add it in the php code, you can add it dynamically as @madalinivascu says above:

If it is an object:

```
$myObject->myNewProperty = 'My new value'; 
# if it is dynamically and you don't know the name ...
$myObject->{"myNewProperty"} = 'My new value';
```

If it is an array:

```
$myArray['myNewProperty'] = 'My new value';
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this code when value return with multiple object with array

```
 $value[] = $datapages->getCitationDataofquotes($var1);

                for($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++) 
                {
                    $value[$i]->newprop = 'new content';
                }
```